# Почему нет ничего в консоли, как будто код не выполняется?

Tags: python, парсер

Уважаемые, не подскажите почему не работает. Из cmd: D:\Python>py #Имя файла# parse.py Дальше пауза, а потом: D:\Python Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


r = request.get("https://news.google.com/")
html = BS(r.content, "html.parser")

for el in html.select(".VDXfz"):
    title = el.select(".VDXfz")
    print(title[0].text)
```

Comment: Значит, нечего высвечивать ‍♂️

Comment: Вы уверены, что ничего не высвечивает, а не выдает ошибку?

Comment: Я уверен что не высвечивает

Comment: Если вы посмотрите на значения `title` в цикле, то всегда будет выводиться `[]`, а значит обращение к `title[0].text` будет возвращать ошибку `index out of range`

Comment: Vladimir посмотрите, я добавил скриншот комндной строки

Comment: @XimizIvanov Это не отменяет моего замечания выше)

Comment: Ответ заключается в том, что у вас `title` пустой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for el in html.select(".VDXfz"):
    title = el.select(".VDXfz")
    print(title[0].text)
```

Вот на этом месте `html.select(".VDXfz")` - уже список, содержащий содержимое блоков с классом `VDXfz`.
Когда вы проходитесь по списку в цикле, вы для чего-то внутри блока, который УЖЕ вырезан из `.VDXfz` пытаетесь отобрать внутренние блоки с `.VDXfz`.
Ещё одна ошибка в коде - вы импортируете `requests`, а использовать пытаетесь `request`
Ещё ошибка - `.VDXfz` не содержат в себе текста. Пример такого блока, взятый с news.google.com:

```html
<a class="VDXfz" jsname="hXwDdf" jslog="85008; 2:https://nv.ua/biz/markets/ukraina-gazprom-mirovoe-novosti-ukrainy-50062146.html; track:click" href="./articles/CBMiT2h0dHBzOi8vbnYudWEvYml6L21hcmtldHMvdWtyYWluYS1nYXpwcm9tLW1pcm92b2Utbm92b3N0aS11a3JhaW55LTUwMDYyMTQ2Lmh0bWzSAUdodHRwczovL252LnVhL2FtcC91a3JhaW5hLWdhenByb20tbWlyb3ZvZS1ub3Zvc3RpLXVrcmFpbnktNTAwNjIxNDYuaHRtbA?hl=ru&amp;gl=UA&amp;ceid=UA%3Aru" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" aria-hidden="true"></a>
```

Вот решение вашей задачи (если я, конечно, правильно понимаю, что задача заключается в поиске заголовков ссылок):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get("https://news.google.com/")
print(f'[INFO] Получен ответ {r}')
html = BS(r.content, "html.parser")
print('[INFO] Обработка BeautifulSoup завершена')
for el in html.select(".VDXfz+h3>a"):
    print(f'# {el.text}')
```

Но предупреждаю: решение поставленной вами задачи занимает довольно много времени
Результат работы программы:

```html
[INFO] Получен ответ <Response [200]>
[INFO] Обработка BeautifulSoup завершена
# Church shooting: Armed parishioners carried guns because of this Texas law
# Hanukkah stabbing suspect has ‘history of mental illness’ and no ties to hategroups, family says
# Iran warns of 'consequences' after US strikes in Iraq and Syria
# Biden Rebounds, Warren Slows: What We Know About the 2020 Money Race Today
# Greta Thunberg's dad did not support her climate activism. Then he saw how ithelped her beat depression
# Joe Kennedy defends Pelosi's decision to withhold articles of impeachment
# Giuliani calls Swalwell a coward after congressman’s attack
# Long Island science teacher killed in Vermont ski accident
# Marijuana legalization in Illinois, Michigan could trigger interstate tangling
# 2,300 unvaccinated students may not be allowed back to class, Seattle Public Schools warns
# North Korean leader Kim Jong Un calls for "offensive measures"
# Ukraine fears Trump hold on aid exposed vulnerability in war with Russia
# Sudan sentences 27 to death for torturing, killing protester
# Pompeo talks rise in religious attacks, US strikes on Iraq and Syria
# Secure Act includes one critical tax change ‘that will send estate planners reeling’
# A Decade After A Fearful Market Hit Bottom, Stock Bulls Continue Historic Run
# Warren Buffett spends billions to make Iowa the 'Saudi Arabia of wind'
# Tesla to miss delivery forecast and stock to get cut in half, Cowen says
# Galaxy S11 leaks and rumors: 4 rear cameras, battery, price, release date forSamsung's upcoming phone
# MacBook Pro 13-Inch (2019) Under Stress: Heat, Fan, And Noise Control
# Leak shows that the cheaper new Pixel 4a looks so much better than Google’s flagship Pixel 4
# Price mistake alert: Anker’s $80 AirPods rivals were accidentally slashed to $29.99
# Zac Efron has 'bounced back' after becoming ill while filming survival show in Papua New Guinea
# Adam Sandler’s ‘Uncut Gems’ Scores Box Office Record for A24
# 'Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker': Why Is Kelly Marie Tran's Rose Tico Only Onscreen for 76 Seconds?
# ‘Little Women’ Is the Top Box Office Newcomer; ‘Skywalker’ May Fall $100 Million Short of ‘Jedi’
# Giants fire Pat Shurmur, will begin search for third coach in 5 years
# 2019 NFL Playoff Odds, Schedule: Patriots a shockingly small favorite for Wild-Card Weekend against Titans
# 49ers Won a Game of Inches to Clinch the NFC’s No. 1 Seed—and the NFL Playoffs Are Set
# NFL Power Rankings: Final 2019-20 Regular-Season Review and Standings
# Christina Koch Sets A New Record For Women Astronauts
# Humanity's space travel plans, 2020–2030
# The 12 Most Important and Stunning Quantum Experiments of 2019
# Scientists Say They Now Have An Answer To The ‘Oldest Open Question In Astrophysics’
# For Better Brain Health, Preserve Your Hearing
# Make 2020 the Year of Less Sugar
# SC continues to see widespread flu activity as number of flu-related deaths climbs
# Video: Where Resources Are Scarce, A Rural Doctor Takes On The Opioid Crisis : Shots - Health News
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо

Comment: @XimizIvanov если ответ помог, вы можете поставить галочку возле него